# Rerender React component(popup) after certain time period till counter is reached

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a popup which opens up for the first time when user scrolls down the page. I want to show this pop up max 5 times with a delay of 1min after user closes the pop up. Also i want to store the count of times pop up shown to the user 1 to 5 in session storage.

I was able to rerender the component after certain interval but component is getting rerendered upto 10 times.

```
function App () {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true)
    let counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    if(!counter) {
         counter=1
         localStorage.setItem("counter", counter)
    }
    console.count(); // counts no of rerenders
    const timerCheck = () => {
       counter +=1;
       localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
       setVisible(true)
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
        setVisible(false)
        if(counter < 5) {
            const id = setTimeout(timerCheck, 60000)
            return () => clearTimeout(id);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        { visible && 
            <div className="con" onClick={closeModal}>
                    hello 
            </div>
        }
        </>
    )

}
```

Added console.count() statement to check the component rerender count its 10. I expect component to render 5 times only since im closing the pop up 5 times and it shows up 5 times.

Comment: In place of localStorage.counter=counter it would help if you used localStorage.setItem(key, value) to update your count value in localStorage. Refer this link for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage.setItem("key",value) instead of directly updating the localstorage key

Comment: I did try that but that does not solve the problem. I want to reduce the no of react component renders to 5 instead of 10. Due to state update and setTimeout it rerenders 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is being called every time `closeModal` is executed, causing multiple instances of the timer to run. To prevent this, you can use the ``useEffect` hook to set up the timer only once, like this:

```js
function App () {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true)
    let counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
    if(!counter) {
         counter=1
         localStorage.counter=1
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (counter < 5) {
            const id = setTimeout(() => {
                counter += 1;
                localStorage.counter = counter;
                setVisible(true);
            }, 60000)
            return () => clearTimeout(id);
        }
    }, [counter])

    const closeModal = () => {
        setVisible(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
        { visible && 
            <div className="con" onClick={closeModal}>
                    hello 
            </div>
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Masum, it did not completely achieve what i expected. I was able to render the pop up only 3 times. somehow the counter is getting multiple times on 2nd time closing the pop up.